# Shortest distance between a point and multiple lines in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a column of points geometry in table 1 and another column of linestring geometry (these are routes) in table 2.
For each row of the points geometry, how do I find the shortest distance to ANY of the linestring geometry values in table 2.

P.S - Since both are geometry, do I have to convert to ::geography to get distances?

Comment: Search for `shortest distance [postgis]` at the top of the site and you will find many possible solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PostGIS documentation, you can for example use [`ST_ClosestPoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html):

```
SELECT
  ST_AsText( ST_ClosestPoint(pt,line)) AS cp_pt_line,
  ST_AsText( ST_ClosestPoint(line,pt)) AS cp_line_pt
FROM (
  SELECT
    'POINT (160 40)'::geometry AS pt,
    'LINESTRING (10 30, 50 50, 30 110, 70 90, 180 140, 130 190)'::geometry AS line
) AS t;
```

or even better:

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(pt) as pt,
  ST_AsText(cp_line_pt) as cp_line_pt,
  ST_Distance(pt, cp_line_pt) as dist
FROM (
  SELECT
    pt,
    ST_ClosestPoint(line, pt) AS cp_line_pt
  FROM (
    SELECT
      ST_SetSRID('POINT (160 40)'::geometry, 3857) AS pt,
      ST_SetSRID('LINESTRING (10 30, 50 50, 30 110, 70 90, 180 140, 130 190)'::geometry, 3857) AS line
    ) AS t
) foo;
```

which results in:

[image]

I let you play around with this sample and try to figure out how to apply it on your own data set.

Please read carefully throughout the [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) doc to figure out how it works with geography, especially:

> For geometry types returns the minimum 2D Cartesian (planar) distance between two geometries, in projected units (spatial ref units).

> For geography types defaults to return the minimum geodesic distance between two geographies in meters, compute on the spheroid determined by the SRID. If use_spheroid is false, a faster spherical calculation is used.

For a better solution, you can dive into the PostGIS nearest neighbor operator `<->` as described here: https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html

e.g. with something like this:

```
SELECT
  lines.id AS line_id,
  (
    ST_Transform(lines.geom, <your projection crs>)
    <->
    ST_Transform(<your point geometry>, <your projection crs>)
  )::double precision AS distance
FROM
  lines
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1;
-- LIMIT 1 will take the point on lines with the shortest distance
-- to your input point geometry as they are ordered.
```

Now you can build yourself a function with that and call it on all your point geometries.

Or programmatically use that within, e.g. a Python script which reads and stores your point geometries to a list-like structure before feeding it to such kind of SQL query.

As suggested by @geozelot in the comment below, you can directly loop over your table of points in SQL using a `LATERAL` join, e.g.:

```
SELECT
  p.id AS point_id,
  l.id AS line_id,
  distance
FROM points p CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT 
    *,
    ((l.geom) <-> (p.geom)) AS distance
  FROM lines l
  ORDER BY distance
  LIMIT 1
) l;
```

More on this:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM
- https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html

Comment: I do not have a constant point, or a constant linestring, I have columns for both. I don't know how to modify your code to reflect that I want to compare each point to ALL the linestrings! can you please help? I am new to postgis, thanks so much

Comment: Also, my SRID is 0 in the database, so should I just convert to geography instead?

Comment: You've definitely outlined the most favorable concept (`<->` distance operator), but unfortunately its execution is a little off - especially when its application is on multiple tables, and considering the implication on performance, i.e. utilizing a spatial index. The crucial part missing is a `LATERAL` join to a sub-query with `ORDER BY a.geom <-> b.geom LIMIT 1` in it, which can be considered as executing said sub-query in a loop over the joining table. PG can only utilize an index (and make this kind of search performant) when `<->` is used as the (sole) `ORDER BY` item.

Comment: Updated, thanks for the hint @geozelot ! I'm not used to that `LATERAL` statement.